# Best approach for creating the average of multiple profile photos?

Tags: photography

We've all seen composite photos that are a mix of hundreds, or thousands of profile photos. Here's examples:

https://duckduckgo.com/?q=average+look+of+people+from+every+country&t=osx&iax=images&ia=images

https://www.businessinsider.com/faces-of-tomorrow-2011-2

All examples that I've seen were made by an artist/photographer, who took the individual photos themselves, allowing for the most optimal alignment between individual photos.

With image recognition having taken huge leaps since this technique was first developed, is there software out there that can identify faces in individual photos, and then use those to superimpose them onto each other?

Preferably, this would be a MacOS application. But, Windows or Linux are options, too.

An acceptable cost depends on the quality of the output, and the amount of work that would be required to prepare the input. Something in the range of a few hundred euros would probably be a likely maximum.

Comment: Added some extra info.

Comment: Thanks! All well now. Fingers crossed for good recommendations!